# ¿Cómo enviar archivo por Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

estoy terminando de crear el **bot de discord** usando **discord.py**

Y lo que quiero que haga es que envié un archivo **txt**

Ejemplo

> Usuario: ff!nitro
>
> Bot: Aqui estan los codigos
>
> (MANDA ARCHIVO)

**Este es mi codigo**

```
@client.command()
async def nitro(ctx):
   archive = "Dirección del Archivo"
   await ctx.author.send(Archive)
```

**El problema es que envia la dirección y quiero que se envie asi como un usuario normal enviaría el mensaje de un archivo**

Agradezco de ante mano su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La solución sería la siguiente**

*(EL ARCHIVO DEBE DE ESTAR EN LA MISMA CARPETA QUE EL CODIGO)*

```
@client.command()
async def nitro(ctx):
   await ctx.author.send(file=discord.File('NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO.txt'))
```

**Gracias a todos**

Comment: por que reviertes la edición?

Comment: por que no era necesaria la edición